# Different optimal bandwidths of Newey West (1994) in R and STATA

Tags: r, stata, robust-standard-error, neweywest, sandwich

R and STATA gave very different optimal bandwidths for the same data set. It will be greatly appreciated if someone can give me any hint why this happens. Here are two sample codes from R and STATA and their results:

```
rm(list=ls())
library('vars')
library('sandwich')
library('AER')
my.ts=read.csv(file='https://www.dropbox.com/s/btg5i3a2xjyfs1d/sample.csv?dl=1', header=T)
my.ts=as.matrix(my.ts)
dep = my.ts[,2]
reg = my.ts[,-c(1,2,31,32)]
exo = my.ts[,-c(1:4)]
iv = my.ts[,c(31,32)]
m = ivreg(dep~reg-1| exo + iv)
opt.bw = bwNeweyWest(m, prewhite=0)
cat("Optimal Bandwidth:", opt.bw, '\n')
print(coeftest(m, vcov=NeweyWest(m,prewhite=0)))
```

---

```
Optimal Bandwidth: 8.048093 

t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
reg.sum.g.exp     1.106501   0.345920  3.1987  0.001473 ** 
reg.sum.g.rec    -1.923236   1.485894 -1.2943  0.196186    
reg.const.exp     0.278318   0.095520  2.9137  0.003741 ** 
reg.L1.newsy.exp -0.043360   0.060837 -0.7127  0.476373    
reg.L2.newsy.exp -0.160847   0.092446 -1.7399  0.082530 .  
reg.L3.newsy.exp -0.037167   0.059712 -0.6224  0.533953    
reg.L4.newsy.exp  0.101035   0.057360  1.7614  0.078818 .  
reg.L1.y.exp      2.562082   0.327755  7.8171 3.565e-14 ***
reg.L2.y.exp     -0.759036   0.420711 -1.8042  0.071843 .  
reg.L3.y.exp      0.237435   0.344001  0.6902  0.490398    
reg.L4.y.exp     -0.350762   0.296555 -1.1828  0.237490    
reg.L1.g.exp     -3.681902   1.197826 -3.0738  0.002236 ** 
reg.L2.g.exp      1.680821   0.799517  2.1023  0.036058 *  
reg.L3.g.exp      0.248755   0.396698  0.6271  0.530921    
reg.L4.g.exp     -0.271041   0.251835 -1.0763  0.282359    
reg.const.rec     0.069961   0.051694  1.3534  0.176591    
reg.L1.newsy.rec  0.249436   0.229317  1.0877  0.277270    
reg.L2.newsy.rec  0.761978   0.455853  1.6715  0.095279 .  
reg.L3.newsy.rec  0.602214   0.359619  1.6746  0.094678 .  
reg.L4.newsy.rec  0.575172   0.338058  1.7014  0.089528 .  
reg.L1.y.rec      2.824780   0.220032 12.8380 < 2.2e-16 ***
reg.L2.y.rec     -0.591850   0.470803 -1.2571  0.209338    
reg.L3.y.rec     -0.683720   0.551778 -1.2391  0.215917    
reg.L4.y.rec      0.394905   0.318481  1.2400  0.215607    
reg.L1.g.rec      4.605353   2.582563  1.7832  0.075190 .  
reg.L2.g.rec     -1.714590   1.133304 -1.5129  0.130973    
reg.L3.g.rec      0.336162   0.957711  0.3510  0.725741    
reg.L4.g.rec      0.528508   0.854584  0.6184  0.536585    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

### STATA

```
insheet using "https://www.dropbox.com/s/btg5i3a2xjyfs1d/sample.csv?dl=1", clear
tsset v1
ivreg2 sumy constexp l1newsyexp l2newsyexp l3newsyexp l4newsyexp l1yexp l2yexp l3yexp l4yexp l1gexp l2gexp l3gexp l4gexp constrec l1newsyrec l2newsyrec l3newsyrec l4newsyrec l1yrec l2yrec l3yrec l4yrec l1grec l2grec l3grec l4grec (sumgexp sumgrec = newsyexp newsyrec), nocons robust bw(auto)
```

---

```
IV (2SLS) estimation
--------------------

Estimates efficient for homoskedasticity only
Statistics robust to heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation
  kernel=Bartlett; bandwidth=19
  Automatic bw selection according to Newey-West (1994)
  time variable (t):  v1

                                                      Number of obs =      499
                                                      F( 28,   471) = 62459.36
                                                      Prob > F      =   0.0000
Total (centered) SS     =  15.91494644                Centered R2   =   0.9165
Total (uncentered) SS   =  1955.368811                Uncentered R2 =   0.9993
Residual SS             =  1.329025976                Root MSE      =   .05161

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
        sumy |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sumgexp |   1.106502   .3154082     3.51   0.000     .4883132    1.724691
     sumgrec |  -1.923237   1.536398    -1.25   0.211    -4.934522    1.088048
    constexp |    .278318   .0887598     3.14   0.002      .104352    .4522839
  l1newsyexp |  -.0433599   .0520314    -0.83   0.405    -.1453396    .0586197
  l2newsyexp |  -.1608472   .0901899    -1.78   0.075    -.3376161    .0159217
  l3newsyexp |  -.0371676   .0538555    -0.69   0.490    -.1427223    .0683872
  l4newsyexp |   .1010346   .0560071     1.80   0.071    -.0087373    .2108064
      l1yexp |   2.562082   .3485714     7.35   0.000     1.878895    3.245269
      l2yexp |   -.759036   .4096429    -1.85   0.064    -1.561921    .0438494
      l3yexp |   .2374351   .3076886     0.77   0.440    -.3656234    .8404937
      l4yexp |  -.3507623   .2786922    -1.26   0.208    -.8969889    .1954642
      l1gexp |  -3.681904   1.031009    -3.57   0.000    -5.702645   -1.661163
      l2gexp |   1.680822   .6789219     2.48   0.013     .3501592    3.011484
      l3gexp |   .2487545   .3122592     0.80   0.426    -.3632623    .8607714
      l4gexp |  -.2710408   .1723631    -1.57   0.116    -.6088664    .0667847
    constrec |    .069961   .0456136     1.53   0.125    -.0194401     .159362
  l1newsyrec |   .2494359   .2377063     1.05   0.294      -.21646    .7153317
  l2newsyrec |   .7619778   .4796875     1.59   0.112    -.1781925    1.702148
  l3newsyrec |   .6022149   .3502127     1.72   0.086    -.0841893    1.288619
  l4newsyrec |   .5751727   .3356722     1.71   0.087    -.0827327    1.233078
      l1yrec |    2.82478   .1907978    14.81   0.000     2.450823    3.198736
      l2yrec |  -.5918488   .4048256    -1.46   0.144    -1.385292    .2015948
      l3yrec |  -.6837207   .5120002    -1.34   0.182    -1.687223    .3197812
      l4yrec |   .3949049   .3520525     1.12   0.262    -.2951053    1.084915
      l1grec |   4.605354   2.735779     1.68   0.092    -.7566743    9.967383
      l2grec |  -1.714588   .9030786    -1.90   0.058    -3.484589    .0554138
      l3grec |   .3361612    .792788     0.42   0.672    -1.217675    1.889997
      l4grec |   .5285083    .816543     0.65   0.517    -1.071886    2.128903
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Underidentification test (Kleibergen-Paap rk LM statistic):              2.566
                                                   Chi-sq(1) P-val =    0.1092
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Weak identification test (Cragg-Donald Wald F statistic):                1.530
                         (Kleibergen-Paap rk Wald F statistic):          1.147
Stock-Yogo weak ID test critical values: 10% maximal IV size              7.03
                                         15% maximal IV size              4.58
                                         20% maximal IV size              3.95
                                         25% maximal IV size              3.63
Source: Stock-Yogo (2005).  Reproduced by permission.
NB: Critical values are for Cragg-Donald F statistic and i.i.d. errors.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hansen J statistic (overidentification test of all instruments):         0.000
                                                 (equation exactly identified)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:         sumgexp sumgrec
Included instruments: constexp l1newsyexp l2newsyexp l3newsyexp l4newsyexp
                      l1yexp l2yexp l3yexp l4yexp l1gexp l2gexp l3gexp l4gexp
                      constrec l1newsyrec l2newsyrec l3newsyrec l4newsyrec
                      l1yrec l2yrec l3yrec l4yrec l1grec l2grec l3grec l4grec
Excluded instruments: newsyexp newsyrec
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see from the results, point estimates are roughly the same but their robust HAC standard errors are quite different because of different bandwidth choice (8 vs. 19). Both use the Bartlette kernel function. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

---

Updated: September 12, 2017

Here are results when the same bandwidth was used in R. The standard errors are very close to each other.

`print(coeftest(m, vcov=NeweyWest(m,prewhite=0, lag=19)))`

```
t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
reg.sum.g.exp     1.106501   0.316271  3.4986 0.0005121 ***
reg.sum.g.rec    -1.923236   1.548016 -1.2424 0.2147118    
reg.const.exp     0.278318   0.088797  3.1343 0.0018301 ** 
reg.L1.newsy.exp -0.043360   0.051786 -0.8373 0.4028560    
reg.L2.newsy.exp -0.160847   0.090223 -1.7828 0.0752685 .  
reg.L3.newsy.exp -0.037167   0.053407 -0.6959 0.4868195    
reg.L4.newsy.exp  0.101035   0.055891  1.8077 0.0712892 .  
reg.L1.y.exp      2.562082   0.351150  7.2963 1.265e-12 ***
reg.L2.y.exp     -0.759036   0.410291 -1.8500 0.0649403 .  
reg.L3.y.exp      0.237435   0.303414  0.7825 0.4342882    
reg.L4.y.exp     -0.350762   0.275317 -1.2740 0.2032818    
reg.L1.g.exp     -3.681902   1.038019 -3.5470 0.0004286 ***
reg.L2.g.exp      1.680821   0.690575  2.4339 0.0153061 *  
reg.L3.g.exp      0.248755   0.315558  0.7883 0.4309165    
reg.L4.g.exp     -0.271041   0.166783 -1.6251 0.1048072    
reg.const.rec     0.069961   0.044698  1.5652 0.1182075    
reg.L1.newsy.rec  0.249436   0.238441  1.0461 0.2960468    
reg.L2.newsy.rec  0.761978   0.482872  1.5780 0.1152342    
reg.L3.newsy.rec  0.602214   0.353165  1.7052 0.0888183 .  
reg.L4.newsy.rec  0.575172   0.337283  1.7053 0.0887958 .  
reg.L1.y.rec      2.824780   0.189118 14.9366 < 2.2e-16 ***
reg.L2.y.rec     -0.591850   0.399977 -1.4797 0.1396191    
reg.L3.y.rec     -0.683720   0.511684 -1.3362 0.1821243    
reg.L4.y.rec      0.394905   0.355053  1.1122 0.2666013    
reg.L1.g.rec      4.605353   2.761195  1.6679 0.0960034 .  
reg.L2.g.rec     -1.714590   0.900123 -1.9048 0.0574097 .  
reg.L3.g.rec      0.336162   0.775042  0.4337 0.6646802    
reg.L4.g.rec      0.528508   0.814679  0.6487 0.5168276    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Stata is also using a small sample adjustment to the variance of N/(N-K), which R typically does not use. That is probably not enough to explain the difference. If you run the code with the same bandwidth and do this correction, how close are the standard errors then?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thanks for your comment. Yes, the standard errors are quite close to each other when they use the same bandwith.

Comment: Hmm, hard to say what exactly is going on within Stata. My first guess was that just the scores from the second stage instead of the combined first+second stage are used in Stata. However, this would increase the bandwidth only from about 8 to about 9. Note sure what is responsible for the rest of the difference.